# Clarification on edit rejection reasons 2

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

[My edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/282664) was rejected. Yet,

$$-\text{tr}\left[\text{adjoint}\left[(P^{-1}DP+I)\sin(\Omega t)^2(I+P^{-1}DP)\right] (P^{-1}DP\cos(\Omega t)-\cos(\Omega t)P^{-1}DP)\right]$$

is much more readable (and in fact... correct) than 
$-\text{trace}(\text{Adjoint}((P^{-1}DP+I)\sin(\Omega t)^2(I+P^{-1}DP)) (P^{-1}DP\cos(\Omega t)-\cos(\Omega t)P^{-1}DP)$, in my opinion.

Also, my first edit was accepted (did not have time to do all at once) so now the answer looks weird, with both $trace(Adjoint)$ and $\text{tr}(\text{adjoint})$. See the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964373/proof-of-the-conjecture-that-the-kernel-is-of-dimension-2/971763#971763).

I am aware that everybody complaining about rejected edits would be problematic, but I'd like to improve my understanding as I'm getting more and more involved on SEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my opinion, the best attitude in this scenario is...
>
> ## ...RAGE.
>
> ...of the "Those fools! They rejected my work - MINE! I'll show them, **I'LL SHOW THEM *ALL!***" type.
>
> ...followed by a concerted effort to garner [full editing privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). So that you can show them all.

(From [Best attitude when suggested edit is refused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187582/), by Shog9.)

---

Meanwhile, I edited the answer using `\operatorname{}` instead of `\text{}`, and also aligning the long multiline formulas that were split between lines in a non-aligned way.

Comment: OK i'll start by breaking my... [bang!] keYbOaRd... aRgH i hIT The CAp kEY

Comment: I now changed to a new keyboard. I feel much better BTW so I accepted your answer. Curious question: what's the benefit or `\operatorname` instead of `\text`?

Comment: Compare $\text{tr}B$ and $\operatorname{tr}B$, specifically the spacing. This is `\text{tr}B` and `\operatorname{tr}B`. When LaTeX knows it's an operator, it leaves room as in $\sin B$. Also, LaTeX markup is meant to capture the meaning of symbols, not just their appearance. Someone, far in the future, should be able to decide that operator names should be in sans-serif rather than roman font, and change the style of document accordingly.

Comment: @anderstood: I recommend a Unicomp Model M replica. Those are sturdy enough to serve as a nuclear shelter when the time comes to hide. You can bang on them without any repercussions. I would have recommended an original IBM Model M, but it's a shame to beat up a classic.